# loop input to glob and write results to .txt

Tags: python, glob

I'm attempting to us a list of strings as input to glob and write the results respective to each input string as a separate .txt file but have so far been unsuccessful, I've searched for other problems but none seem to looping within a loop as I imagine I will need to? Thanks

```
import os
import glob

# Generate a list of modis data julian days
julian_days = []

for day in range(1,365, 8):
    julian_days.append(str('MOD09A1.A2015' + (str('{:03d}'.format(day))) +'*.hdf'))

for day in julian_days:
    results = glob.glob(str(day))
    myfile = open(((str(day[:-5])) + '.txt'), "w")
    for line in results:
        myfile.write(results, lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file names you are looking for with glob? I suspect your `day` string isn't correct.

Comment: MOD09A1.A2015001.h13v04.005.2015010071352.hdf is an example of one of the files, but I believe the glob is working fine as when i print the results of it I see the correct files